# Standalone ESXi Cannot Run Upgrade Process

Tags: vmware-esxi

Trying to manually run an upgrade from ESXi 5.0 to ESXi 5.1.
My image bundle is stored on the first datastore `/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard`, I am running the command `esxcli software profile update -d /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard.zip -p ESXi-5.1.0-799733-standard`.

The system responds with `Got no data from process /usr/lib/vmware/esxcli-software profile.update`

I have read some similar [posts](https://serverfault.com/questions/385770/how-to-update-esxi-5), but nothing that seems to be in the same boat as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. This is caused by the ESXi host not having a static scratch storage. Even though the system creates a temporary self storage, it leaves a strange descriptor in place for the log file: `/dev/log`, and of course the python scripts fail to write to `/dev/log` causing all `esxcli` commands to fail with "Got no data".

Adding a static scratch fix my problem.

ESXi 5.1 is faaast.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. In our case there was a problem with the system disk. The system disk was dead. We tried reboot our server bet server won't start any more - failed boot ESXi. So we put in server new drive and install esxi. We register our existing VM after esxi installation. Problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).